# Nest multisearch query writing as object initializer Syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a multiSearch query as below. Basically I query product and category types. I would like to make this query optional without writing same code again. 
Basically in some cases I want to query only product type, that means that it will not multisearch but a search query. How can I split this query into 2 search queries. Something like below I think.

```
    return Client.MultiSearch(ms => ms
        .Search<Product>("products", s => s
        .Index(IndexName)
        .Explain(explain)
          .Query(q => q
             .Bool(b => b
                 .Should(
                     sh => sh.MultiMatch(qs => qs
                         .Fields(d => d                         
                             .Field(Name + ".raw", NameBoost + 0.5)
                             .Field(Name, NameBoost)                            
                            .Type(TextQueryType.BestFields)
                            .Query(key))
                            ))).From(startfrom).Size(size))
.Search<Category>("categories", s => s
.Index(IndexName)
.Explain(explain)
.Query(q => q.
Bool(b => b.
Should(sh => sh.
MultiMatch(m => m
.Fields(d => d
.Field(f => f.Name, NameBoost)
.Field(p => p.Name.Suffix("raw"), NameBoost + 0.5)).Type(TextQueryType.BestFields)
.Query(key)
)
))).From(startfrom).Size(size))
);
```

something like this below. I guess that it is called  object initializer Syntax according to [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/writing-queries.html#_object_initializer_syntax_ois_2) article

Client.MultiSearch (SearchProductQuery && SearchCategoryQuery)

is it possible?

Comment: What version of NEST are you using? Also, what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: @RussCam I am using for both 2.1.0 version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fluent API multi search

```
client.MultiSearch(ms => ms
    .Search<Product>("products", s => s
        .Index(IndexName)
        .Explain(explain)
        .Query(q => q
           .Bool(b => b
                .Should(sh => sh
                    .MultiMatch(qs => qs
                        .Fields(d => d
                            .Field(Name + ".raw", NameBoost + 0.5)
                            .Field(Name, NameBoost)
                        )
                        .Type(TextQueryType.BestFields)
                        .Query(key)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        .From(startfrom)
        .Size(size)
    )
    .Search<Category>("categories", s => s
        .Index(IndexName)
        .Explain(explain)
        .Query(q => q
            .Bool(b => b
                .Should(sh => sh
                    .MultiMatch(m => m
                        .Fields(d => d
                            .Field(f => f.Name, NameBoost)
                            .Field(p => p.Name.Suffix("raw"), NameBoost + 0.5)
                        )
                        .Type(TextQueryType.BestFields)
                        .Query(key)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        .From(startfrom)
        .Size(size)
    )
);
```

would be this OIS API multi search

```
var multiSearch = new MultiSearchRequest
{
    Operations = new Dictionary<string, ISearchRequest>
    {
        { "products", new SearchRequest<Product>(IndexName)
            {
                Explain = true,
                Query = new BoolQuery
                {
                    Should = new QueryContainer[] {
                        new MultiMatchQuery
                        {
                            Fields = 
                                ((Fields)Field.Create(Name + ".raw", NameBoost + 0.5))
                                .And(Name, NameBoost),
                            Type = TextQueryType.BestFields,
                            Query = key
                        }
                    }
                },
                From = startfrom,
                Size = size
            }
        },
        { "categories", new SearchRequest<Category>(IndexName)
            {
                Explain = true,
                Query = new BoolQuery
                {
                    Should = new QueryContainer[] {
                        new MultiMatchQuery
                        {
                            Fields =    
                                ((Fields)Infer.Field<Category>(f => f.Name, NameBoost))
                                .And<Category>(f => f.Name.Suffix("raw"), NameBoost + 0.5),
                            Type = TextQueryType.BestFields,
                            Query = key
                        }
                    }
                },
                From = startfrom,
                Size = size
            }
        },
    }
};

client.MultiSearch(multiSearch);
```

Take a look at the [multi search integration tests](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/2.x/src/Tests/Search/MultiSearch/MultiSearchApiTests.cs) for another example. I'll look at getting this added to [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/index.html).

Comment: is there any performance difference between them? I see that for product you used Field.Create for category Infer.Field<Category>? what is the difference? you added as alternative or any purpose?

Comment: I just showed them as alternative ways of getting a field. Strings are faster than expressions but you get no type safety nor ease of refactoring (`nameof(Type.Property)` can help here)

Comment: regarding performance.  I wanted to compare my original with the field inference. Is my original one actually also a field inference? I went through this link and It tells me that with C# 6, I can use just like my original one. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/field-inference.html#nest-infer

Comment: strings are accepted _verbatim_ i.e. they undergo _no inference_ so if you use strings, you need to ensure that they match the field names in the mapping e.g. case has to be correct. Expressions are inferred so e.g. with the default inference, `f => f.Name` will be inferred as `"name"`